# How to attach online audio file to email in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

My app is playing ringtones from url with ".m4r" extension, I put them in an array called itemArray like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Ringtones";

    itemArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Song Title1", @"song", @"Unknown", @"artise", @"http://www.mywebsite.com/", @"url", @"song.m4r", @"songId", nil],
                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Song Title2", @"song", @"Unknown", @"artise", @"http://www.mywebsite.com/", @"url", @"song.m4r", @"songId", nil],
                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Song Title3", @"song", @"Unknown", @"artise", @"http://www.mywebsite.com/", @"url", @"song.m4r", @"songId", nil],
                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Song Title4", @"song", @"Unknown", @"artise", @"http://www.mywebsite.com/", @"url", @"song.m4r", @"songId", nil], nil] retain];
}
```

Now what I need to do is giving users the option to attach these files to email when tap on the download button as shown below:

```
- (void)downloadAudio:(DownloadButton *)dwnButton{
    NSInteger index = dwnButton.tag;
    NSString *selectedFile = [itemArray objectAtIndex:index];
   [self showEmail:selectedFile];
}

- (void)showEmail:(NSString *)file{

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

        NSString *emailTitle = @"Ringtones";
        NSString *messageBody = @"Enjoy our Awesome ringtones!";
        NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""];

        MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
        [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
        [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", _audioPlayer.url, _audioPlayer.songId];
        NSArray *filepart = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        NSString *filename = [filepart lastObject];


        // Get the resource path and read the file using NSData
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"m4r"];
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        // Add attachment
        [mc addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"audio/mpeg-4" fileName:filename];

        // Present mail view controller on screen
        [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];

        [mc release];
    }
    else{

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                               delegate:nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller  didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error{

    switch (result){

        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
        break;

        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
        break;

        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
        break;

        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
        break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
        break;
    }

    // Remove the mail view
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

My problem is every time I tap on the download button the App crashes with "Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSInternalInconsistencyException`, reason: `-[MFMailComposeInternalViewController addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:] attachment must not be nil.`

*** First throw call stack:
(0x1938091b8 0x19224055c 0x19380908c 0x1942c102c 0x19ffc64b0 0x1000605f8 0x10006033c 0x1996f3d30 0x1996f3cb0 0x1996de128 0x1996f359c 0x199c7e628 0x199c7a6c0 0x199c7a1e0 0x199c7949c 0x1996ee30c 0x1996beda0 0x199ea875c 0x199ea2130 0x1937b6b5c 0x1937b64a4 0x1937b40a4 0x1936e22b8 0x195196198 0x1997297fc 0x199724534 0x1000bbc2c 0x1926c55b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" error.

[BTW: The app is running on my real device not the simulator]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [MFMailComposeInternalViewController addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:] attachment must not be nil

The `fileData` to be sent as attachment in the mail is `nil` when `[mc addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"audio/mpeg-4" fileName:filename];`
 is invoked. That is the source of the crash.

Fetching remote content by the `dataWithContentsOfFile:` is not recommended.

You must consider using [`NSURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html) APIs. 
[This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started) & [this](http://hayageek.com/ios-nsurlsession-example/) are good reads on the topic.

An alternate implementation can be as:

```
- (void)showEmail:(NSString *)file{

    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

        NSURLSession *sessionWithoutDelegate = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", _audioPlayer.url, _audioPlayer.songId];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        [[sessionWithoutDelegate dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            NSString *emailTitle = @"Ringtones";
            NSString *messageBody = @"Enjoy our Awesome ringtones!";
            NSArray *toRecipents = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@""];

            MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
            [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
            [mc setToRecipients:toRecipents];

            NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", _audioPlayer.url, _audioPlayer.songId];

            NSArray *filepart = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
            NSString *filename = filepart.lastObject;

            // use the downloaded data here
            [mc addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"audio/mpeg-4" fileName:filename]; 

            [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];

        }] resume];
    }
    else{
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: @ ystack Thanks for the answer, in fact your answer is working with some conditions, what I mean is I have to press the play button for each file to be able to tap the download button, but when I tap on the download button right after the app launches the app crashes. I don't know exactly what is the problem. Do you have any idea? Do I need to save the file first and then attach it? If this is the case, how can I approach this?